# React Routers don't show up in the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to do a page with "Login" and "Sign up" buttons that will redirect me to the Login and Sign up pages. I tried multiple things and I'm out of ideas so here's the code:

App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import TextButtons from "./components/firstpage";
import './stylesheets/signUpStyle.css'
import './stylesheets/firstPageStyle.css'
import './stylesheets/loginStyle.css'

import React from "react";

function App() {
  return (
      <div className="App">
        <TextButtons/>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

firstpage.js:

```
import React from 'react'

import {
    BrowserRouter,
    Routes,
    Route,
    Link
} from "react-router-dom";

import Form from "./signup";
import FormLogin from "./login";

const TextButtons = () =>
{
    return (
        <div id="text_and_buttons">
            <div id="text">
                <p id="CMS">Conference Management System</p>
            </div>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route exact path="/signup" element={<Form/>}/>
                    <Route exact path="/login" element={<FormLogin/>}/>
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TextButtons
```

Not that important here but if needed, these are the login and sign up files:

signup.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'


class Form extends Component
{
    render() {
        return (
            <>
            <form action="http://localhost:8080/signUp/accountRegistered" method="POST">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>Sign up</h1>
                    <hr />

                    <label for = "firstname"><b>First name</b></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter first name" name="firstname" id="firstname" required />

                    <label for = "lastname"><b>Last name</b></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter last name" name="lastname" id="lastname" required />

                    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" id="email" required />

                    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" id="psw" minlength="8" required />

                    <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" id="psw-repeat" minlength="8" required />

                    <label for="description"><b>Description</b></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a short description" name="description" id="description" />
                    <hr />
                    <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Register</button>
                </div>
            </form>

            <div class="container login">
                <p>Already have an account? <a href="/login">Login</a>.</p>
            </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default Form
```

and login.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class FormLogin extends Component
{
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <form action="http://localhost:8080/signIn/connected" method="POST">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h1>Login</h1>
                        <hr/>

                        <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" id="email" required />

                        <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" id="psw" minlength="8" required />

                        <hr/>
                        <button type="submit" class="loginbtn">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <div class="container signup">
                    <p>Do not have an account? <a href="/signUp">Sign up</a>.</p>
                </div>
            </>

        )
    }
}

export default FormLogin
```

I think the problem is in firstpage.js, I can only see the div with the text on my page. Help??

Comment: If you navigate to `"/signup"` or `"/login"` do the routes get matched and render their routed content? I don't see any links to your routes rendered anywhere, but you should be able to manually enter the paths in the address bar. I'm certain if you checked the console log you'd see a warning about a missing route for `"/"` path as well. Are there any other errors/warnings in the console?

Comment: @DrewReese nope, no warning about that in the console log. I can't even see the links to navigate to signup or login, so I wouldn't know if they render to the routed content. My page is pretty much blank in the browser.

Comment: Have you included all relevant code? I see where you import the `Link` component, but I don't see it rendered into the DOM anywhere. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Other than this I see no overt issues with the code. What versions of React and `react-router-dom` are installed? Please run `npm list react react-router-dom` from the project director and report back.

Comment: Your code is running. Check this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-yonath-wzygj0?file=/TextButtons.js) . Just go to `/login` or `/signup` in Codesandbox's browser

Comment: @DrewReese the unused imports are there because I tried multiple versions before and I forgot to delete them before posting, my bad. I have version 6 last time I checked, so the syntax should be correct (like Routes instead of Switch)

Comment: Ok, just checking. Yeah, you should be able to manually navigate to either of your routes and see the routed content then. It's not clear what any issue is from *just* this code. Could you try creating a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: @Inder I don't see the login and signup in the browser, it's just the title "Conference Management System"

Comment: You have to add `/login` in codesandbox's browser window path on the right.

Comment: Manually type the paths in the sandbox's address bar since you don't have any links to the pages. The routes are working in @Inder's sandbox.

Comment: @Inder ooohh I see, I thought I was supposed to see links on the page, like some <a> tags that would redirect me to the other pages lol, thanks!!

Comment: @DrewReese yeah I didn't realise I wouldn't have anything on the actual page, I was expecting something else, my bad

Comment: React is pretty magical, but not automagical... some things are still manual, like rendering links to the routes you have.  I voted to close as "Unreproducible". Cheers and good luck!